# footnote/marginpar inside table inside csquotes blockquote

Tags: footnotes, memoir, marginpar, csquotes

I need to put a table inside a blockquote, and the table has both footnotes and marginpars (I know, quite the convolution, but such is the manuscript I am transcribing).

The below version gives a `Float(s) lost` error, but if allowed to run displays the table fine albeit the notes are lost.

I have tried `tabularx` and `tabulary`, the `savenotes` environment from `footnote` to no avail.

Also: The offset vertical alignment of the third row is due to the marginpar. Can this be fixed?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,final]{memoir}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{marvosym} % \Pfund symbol

\begin{document}

Four days later, the feudal lord wrote that the priest may \blockquote{yearly obtain the rent from\\%
{\scriptsize\begin{tabular}{b{0.4\textwidth} c c c}%
    The abandoned farm which he uses \dotfill & 1~\Pfund{}~Rye & 1~\Pfund{}~Barley & 1~Barrel\footnote{%
        So it says (Perhaps \Pfund{} is meant?)%
    }~Oats \\%
    Another farm \dotfill & ,, --- & ,, --- & 1 -- --- \\%
    Two farms in Village\marginpar{\emph{The Village farms}}\footnote{%
        These farms burned in 16xx%
    }\dotfill & 3 --- & 3 --- & 6 --- \\%
    \midrule%
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{in total:} & 4 --- & 4 --- & 8 --- \\%
\end{tabular}}\\%
which he may use to maintain certain ...} This was received by ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason for the lost float error is the `\marginpar` that is used inside of a non-floating environment. Replacing `\marginpar` by `\sidepar` should fix this.  For the footnotes, you might want to use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` instead of `\footnote`.

Comment: `\sidepar` works, thanks for that one. The `\footnotetext` doesn't show up though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described error is caused by the usage of `\marginpar` inside of a non-floating environment. Replacing `\maginpar` by `\sidepar` will work. For the `footnotes` you can then use the `footnote` package and its `savenotes` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,final]{memoir}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{marvosym} % \Pfund symbol
\usepackage{footnote}

\begin{document}


    Four days later, the feudal lord wrote that the priest may \blockquote{yearly obtain the rent from

\begin{savenotes}
  \scriptsize
  \begin{tabular}{b{0.4\textwidth} c c c}%
    The abandoned farm which he uses \dotfill & 1~\Pfund{}~Rye & 1~\Pfund{}~Barley & 1~Barrel\footnote{So it says (Perhaps \Pfund{} is meant?)}~Oats \\%
    Another farm \dotfill & ,, --- & ,, --- & 1 -- --- \\%
    Two farms in Village\sidepar{\emph{The Village farms}}\footnote{These farms burned in 16xx}\dotfill & 3 --- & 3 --- & 6 --- \\%
    \midrule%
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{in total:} & 4 --- & 4 --- & 8 --- \\%
\end{tabular}
\end{savenotes}

which he may use to maintain certain ...} This was received by ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestions for the vertical offset in the village line?